# How to set a Thread-local in the thread provided by tomcat?

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, threadpool, thread-local

So, Tomcat has its own thread-pool and for each request, it gets a thread (Thread A)from this pool and uses and clears the same after completion.

Is there a way to initialise a thread-local variable when this thread (Thread A) gets initialised?

Purpose here is to calculate the processing time, where I need to set a time on thread creation and will be using this time to calculate the before processing time before sending out to the client.

Comment: The best way to manage this from another thread is to use a thread safe `Map&lt;Thread, MyData&gt;`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, this is the solution i have followed before, but then the time that tomcat takes to process and reach the first configured filter will be excluded, even-though it is very minimal. I was hoping that I could log this time too.

Comment: You could store the time from the first read and look it up later. Ideally what you want is the time the packet was on the wire (which you can do with Solarflare cards) so you know the entire delay from the switch to Java.  For your use case, you might find that sub-millisecond delays are not so important esp if you loo at the 99%ile latencies (worst 1 in 100)

Comment: Yes, also I stumbled upon something in ThreadMXBean "ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean().getCurrentThreadCpuTime()" which outputs the processing time in nanoseconds. Ill just leave it here, if this is useful for someone.

Comment: That is the total CPU time since the thread started so will include everything the thread did for previous requests.

Comment: Yes. Also it seems to return only the time in RUNNING state. I will be then storing the data(entry time) from the first filter and calculate it based on needs. Will have this opened, incase someone comes up with another solution to it.

Comment: You need to take a `System.nanoTime()` as early as you can in the server, i.e. immediately after the Socket read() if possible. This might require injecting code in the server to do this. Have you had a look at the source?

Comment: @PeterLawrey I logged the initial time as a thread-local variable at the first configured filter i.e., where my first  application code begins and I used this as and when required.

Answer (score 2):

The processing time corresponds to the *time-taken* field of the [Extended Access Log Valve](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Extended_Access_Log_Valve). Maybe you don't need to reinvent the wheel in this case.

Comment: Is this time-taken depends on the network latency of the client from where a request is initiated?

Comment: No, the application is writing and flushing its OutputStream and after that it's the network interface which will send the traffic to the client. If the client has a poor connection, you should not see it with this field.

Comment: Ok. But in this case, i need to calculate the execution time in the system/server and have implemented the solution suggested by @Peter Lawrey.

Comment: My answer takes 2 minutes to implement, and it would be nice if you could post metrics from both methods once you have finished and made conclusions.

Comment: Yes, i agree. But I would be going with Peter's suggestion as i would not want to consider the connection speed in the clients side. And yes, I will try to post the metrics.